# slurm with K8s or Kubeflow possible?

Tags: kubernetes, kubeflow, kubeflow-pipelines

I understand that both Slurm and Kubeflow/K8s are workload manager. we wanted to leverage features of slurm parallelism etc., and use with Kubeflow or Kubernetes for ML workflow, is it possible? can they coexist or work together?

Example: We want to submit training job from Kubeflow notebook, it should work with Slrum partition to create a queue or schedule a job, if no GPU available, job should be in pending and run once the resource available?

Leverage Slrum + I understand that both Slurm and Kubeflow/K8s are workload manager.

Comment: While Stack Overflow does permit certain questions about Kubernetes, we require that they (like all questions asked here) be specifically related to programming. This question does not appear to be specifically related to programming, which makes it off-topic here.

Comment: The question is why do you want to mix them, Kubeflow already [runs in parallel.][1].

If you want something like the kubeflow UI to run jobs on a slurm backend. You may want to explore a jupyther hub backed by slurm solution. like [thisone][2] 


  [1]: https://www.kubeflow.org/docs/components/pipelines/v2/pipelines/control-flow/#parallel-looping-dslparallelfor
  [2]: https://scicomp.ethz.ch/wiki/JupyterHub

Comment: https://www.dkube.io/post/mlops-on-hpc-slurm-with-kubeflow